# How to get handle to IPC?

Tags: electron

In main.js, I'm doing this:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipc} = require('electron')
window-two = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, show: false})
...
ipc.on('second-window', (event, arg)=> {
    window-two.show()
})
```

This always results in the following javascript error on startup:

> A JavaScript error occurred in the main process Uncaught Exception:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
>       at Object. (/myapp/main.js:11:4)

Line 11 is the `ipc.on()` call. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Change `const {app, BrowserWindow, ipc} = require('electron')` to:

```
const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain} = require('electron')

ipcMain.on('second-window', (event, arg)=> {
    window-two.show()
})
```